# How to remove items using linq

Tags: c#, linq, filter

I have the following array, which represents the items I'm trying to remove from a certain data structure instance:

```
string[] diseasesToRemove = new string[] { "D1", "D3", "D5" };
```

I'm able to do it using the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < healthGroup.DiseaseGroups.Length; i++)
{
    var dgDiseases = new List<Disease>(healthGroup.DiseaseGroups[i].Diseases);
    for (int j = 0; j < dgDiseases.Count; j++)
    {
        if (diseasesToRemove.Contains(dgDiseases[j].Name))
        {                 
            dgDiseases.RemoveAt(j);
            j--;
        }
    }
    healthGroup.DiseaseGroups[i].Diseases = dgDiseases.ToArray();
}
```

However, I'm sure there's a better way using Linq or something else. Is there?

Here are the classes:

```
public class HealthGroup
{
    public DiseaseGroup[] DiseaseGroups { get; set; }

    public HealthGroup(DiseaseGroup[] diseaseGroups)
    {
        DiseaseGroups = diseaseGroups;
    }
}

public class DiseaseGroup
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Disease[] Diseases;

    public DiseaseGroup(string name, Disease[] diseases)
    {
        Name = name;
        Diseases = diseases;
    }
}

public class Disease
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "My Disease";
    public int Risk { get; set; } = 7;

    public Disease(string name, int risk)
    {
        Name = name;
        Risk = risk;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Name} with risk {Risk}";
    }
}
```

And some boilerplate to generate the instance:

```
Disease d1 = new Disease("D1", 1);
Disease d2 = new Disease("D2", 2);
Disease d3 = new Disease("D3", 3);
Disease d4 = new Disease("D4", 4);
Disease d5 = new Disease("D5", 5);
Disease d6 = new Disease("D6", 6);
Disease d7 = new Disease("D7", 7);

DiseaseGroup dg1 = new DiseaseGroup("DG1", new Disease[] { d1, d2 });
DiseaseGroup dg2 = new DiseaseGroup("DG2", new Disease[] { d3, d4, d5 });
DiseaseGroup dg3 = new DiseaseGroup("DG3", new Disease[] { d6, d7 });

HealthGroup healthGroup = new HealthGroup(new DiseaseGroup[] { dg1, dg2, dg3 });
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of removing the C# tag from your question _title_ as per [tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging).

Comment: LINQ isn't so good for deleting (it comes from a functional perspective, where all variables are immutable). But you can use it to generate a list that replaces the old one.

Comment: @JohnWu generating a new item would work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `Where` to simplify the code to this:

```
foreach (var diseaseGroup in healthGroup.DiseaseGroups)
{
    diseaseGroup.Diseases 
        = diseaseGroup.Diseases.Where(g => !diseasesToRemove.Contains(g.Name)).ToArray();
}
```

Of course, like the original code, this generates a new list. A more performant option (albeit non-LINQ) might be to make `Diseases` a `List<Disease>`:

```
public class DiseaseGroup
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Disease> Diseases;

    public DiseaseGroup(string name, Disease[] diseases)
    {
        Name = name;
        Diseases = new List<Disease>(diseases);
    }
}
```

and then you could use similar code without the overhead of generating a new list and new array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < healthGroup.DiseaseGroups.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = healthGroup.DiseaseGroups[i].Diseases.Count - 1; j >= 0; --j)
    {
        if (diseasesToRemove.Contains(healthGroup.DiseaseGroups[i].Diseases[j].Name))
        {                 
            healthGroup.DiseaseGroups[i].Diseases.RemoveAt(j);
        }
    }
}
```

I also modified your for loop to work backwards to resolve the problem you had with the `--j` part.

And, instead of using a `string[]` for `diseasesToRemove`, for a large set of items, it would probably be better to use a `HashSet<string>` to store the diseases.

---

Edit to include requested one-liner:

```
healthGroup.DiseaseGroups = healthGroup.DiseaseGroups.Select(g => { return g.Diseases = g.Diseases.Where(g => !diseasesToRemove.Contains(g.Name)).ToArray(); }).ToArray();
```

This is abusing select a little, however :-)

Comment: Up-voted for simplicity.  [He should have no reason to be concerned with performance until there is actually a performance problem](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/).

Comment: @Erik That's true, but I wanted to give two options so that OP can make the call.

Comment: @Erik Philips That proposed non-LINQ alternate is NOT micro-optimization.   Micro-optimization is about trying to squeeze that extra little bit out of performance and dwelling on it.  LINQ can be a pig so you could be talking about the difference between a simple line of code that takes 10 times longer to run, or more verbose, efficient code.  Hundreds of these choices of simplicity over performance add up and one day you're stuck in line at an airport waiting forever to get your boarding pass.  Dealing with them after the fact is much more difficult than using basic diligence to begin with.

Comment: @JimBerg Can you show an example of a Linq statement that takes 10 times longer to run than an equivalent loop?

Comment: Any way I can do this with a one-liner? Otherwise the first option in this answer looks great.

Comment: @Johnny added a solution.

Comment: @D Stanley, it's not necessarily the LINQ that's 10 times slower, but the thought processes that it inspires.   "Can I do it in one line" vs. "how can I do this efficiently."  A developer is able to put together some single line of code to extract an answer without much thought as to how it works behind the scenes rather than thinking it through.  Say I have a list of  2000 items that each have a unique ID.  If I want the item with ID=1500 I can say var x = list.Single(x => x.ID == 1500), and boom, an answer.  Or do I store the items in a dictionary keyed on ID?  Which is better?

Comment: @John really appreciate the help. Query looks correct but I'm getting an error: `The type arguments for method Enumerable.Select<> cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly`

Comment: @Johnny Sorry, I accidentally missed out an important keyword :)

Comment: If you change to a list you can use `RemoveAll`

Answer (score 2):

These sorts of filtering jobs can be nicely expressed in terms of joins. They solve the problem of repeatedly iterating one group to check for matches in the other group (`.Contains` here is O(n) and is called frequently... this doesn't need to happen).

Unfortunately, linq-to-objects only does inner joins out of the box, but a much-reused extension method that I keep around simplifies the job of performing set-based left-outer joins.

If you perform a left-outer join between the diseases and `diseasesToRemove`, then you select items from the left-hand collection of the join (`healthGroup.DiseaseGroups[i].Diseases`) that don't match anything on the right-hand collection (`diseasesToRemove`), then you'll have removed anything that has a match.

Using the extension method `.LeftOuterJoin` (listed below), you can filter your arrays as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < healthGroup.DiseaseGroups.Length; i++)
{
    healthGroup.DiseaseGroups[i].Diseases =
        healthGroup.DiseaseGroups[i].Diseases
            .LeftOuterJoin(
                diseasesToRemove,
                d => d.Name,
                dr => dr,
                (d, dr) => ( d, dr ))
            .Where(x => x.dr == null)
            .Select(x => x.d)
            .ToArray();

}
```

A left-outer join extension method:

```
public static class JoinExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> LeftOuterJoin<TLeft, TRight, TKey, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<TLeft> leftSeq,
        IEnumerable<TRight> rightSeq,
        Func<TLeft, TKey> keySelectorLeft,
        Func<TRight, TKey> keySelectorRight,
        Func<TLeft, TRight, TResult> projectionSelector)
    {
        return leftSeq
            .GroupJoin(
                rightSeq,
                keySelectorLeft,
                keySelectorRight,
                (leftItem, rightItems) => new { leftItem, rightItems })
            .SelectMany(
                x => x.rightItems.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                (x, rightItem) => projectionSelector(x.leftItem, rightItem));
    }
}
```